# using Angular4 post image in Django API get error data was not file

Tags: python, django, angular

This is my angular front-end using this i try to send image in Django API

this Is my **Home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  homeObj:object = {};
  image = [];
  addSaveData = function(home){
    this.homeObj = {

      "image" : home.image
    }
    let _url:string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/Home/Homemodel/';
    this.http.post(_url, this.homeObj).subscribe(( res:Response) =>{
      console.log(res);
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

this is my home.component.html 
this is my simple form design and create function **addSaveData** using this function i try to post image

```
<div id="headder" class="container"><h3>POST METHOD</h3></div>
<form  class="container" id="formNewPost" name="formNewPost" #postData = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "addSaveData(postData.value)">
  <input type="file" name="image" id="image" ngModel>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;margin-bottom:15px;" type="submit" value="POST">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set header
`Content-Type: multipart/form-data` for your request and encode your payload in appropriate form (take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

```
let input = new FormData();
input.append('image', home.image);
let _url:string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/Home/Homemodel/';
this.http.post(_url, input).subscribe(( res:Response) =>{
  console.log(res);
})
```

Note: home.image should be File object